# Affine quantum groups of type A

Tags: quantum-groups, rt.representation-theory

I have a general question regarding quantum groups. It seems to me that the representation theory of the algebra $\mathcal{U}_q(\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}}_{e-1})$ has many parallels with the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_{e-1}$. Why is it this algebra which shares so much in common with $\mathfrak{sl}_{e-1}$ rather than its universal enveloping algebra $\mathcal{U}_q(\mathfrak{sl}_{e-1})$? ($\mathcal{U}_q(\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}}_{e-1})$ is the quantised universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_{e-1}\otimes \mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]\oplus \mathbf{C}c\oplus \mathbf{C}d$).

---

**Edit:** Let me try to formulate the question more precisely. Let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}_{e-1}\otimes \mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]\oplus \mathbb{C}c\oplus \mathbb{C}d$ and let $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ be its quantised universal enveloping algebra. Then the representation theory of $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ has a lot in common with the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_{e-1}$, for example there is a theory of integrable highest weight modules for the two objects and their finite-dimensional irreducible modules have a similar appearance. I am wondering why it is this algebra which shares properties with $\mathfrak{sl}_{e-1}$, rather than its own quantised universal enveloping algebra $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_{e-1})$. If this doesn't make sense, then I mustn't understand something!

Comment: Clinton- I don't follow your question.  The representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_e$ (as a Lie algebra) and that of $U(\mathfrak{sl}_e)$ (as an associative algebra) are the same thing (they are equivalent categories).  For this question to make sense, you need to clarify what distinction you're making.

Comment: Yes I understand that. My question is why is the representation theory of the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ so similar to the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_e$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra above. 

Comment: the quantised universal enveloping algebra*

Comment: As Ben observes, the question needs more precise formulation. By now there has been a lot of study of relationships among module categories (or derived categories), which tends to get highly sophisticated but also interesting. See for example a 2004 JAMS paper and its references: http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2004-17-03/S0894-0347-04-00454-0/   Earlier Kazhdan-Lusztig worked out the subtle connection between certain representations of an affine Lie algebra and representations of a quantum group at a root of unity.  Your type A case is combinatorially best behaved.


Comment: Clinton- Your question is still pretty unclear and hard to answer.  In general questions about **why** something is so are pretty hard to answer, but you also need to be a lot more specific about what facts you think need explaining.  **Lots** of algebras have theories of highest weight modules.

Comment: Yes. Let's just look at $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. Then there is one irreducible for each dimension, and on this module $e$ and $f$ act as lowering and raising operators respectively, while $h$ acts semisimply. This is a full list of (finite-dimensional) irreducible modules. The list of (finite-dimensional) irreducible modules for `$U_q(g)$` is very similar and looks like a $q$-analogue of the theory for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. Why is it **this** algebra which has these properties?

Comment: Clinton, I am sorry to press you further, but I still do not understand your question. For any simple finite dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, and $q$ NOT a root of unity, the finite dimensional representation theory of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ are essentially the "same" in a precise sense. On the other hand, (unless I am making a huge mental blunder) there is no finite dimensional representation theory of $U_q(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ for the $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$ you have written down. 

If you remove the scaling element, then there is are . . . 

Comment: (Cont.) finite dimensional representations, and this is a very interesting subject. For this, I would recommend you take a look on Mathscinet at some of the papers by Chari and Pressely. 

Comment: I understand this. However my question is not about $\mathfrak{g}$ and $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ for the **same** algebra. My question is about the similarities between the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_e$ and $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the **different** algebra I defined above. 

Answer (score 3):

Hm, are you asking about the similarities between the representation theory of non quantum affine algebras (
`$\mathcal{U}(\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}}_{e-1})$`) and that of the quantum group `\$\mathcal{U}q(\mathfrak{sl}{e-1})$` corresponding to the finite dimensional simple Lie algebra?

That similarity is part of a wider pattern, see the famous picture on the cover of the Etingof, Frenkel and Kirillov book on Representation theory:

http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=LrIpQIpvRzMC&oi=fnd&pg=PR13&dq=etingof+representation+theory&ots=g_V9CpeCYe&sig=44-V8VxDAV6DFQSA8nE-zH4dCsg